# Cálculo com filtro de datas e IDs, Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Bom dia,

Preciso criar uma medida que faça o seguinte cálculo:

(Valor linha)/(Valor inicial)

No entanto o cálculo deve ser feito respeitando-se o ID (não dividir por valores de outros IDs, e a base deve ser dinâmica com o filtro de datas).

Abaixo o formato de tabela que possuo (todos os dados são colunas na base).

Como exemplo, os primeiros valores do ID 9 deveriam ficar: (3,21/3,21) = 1; (3,24/3,21) = 1,009.

Criei varias medidas mas não obtive sucesso na execução da tarefa.

Desde já agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar a `DIVIDE(Tabela['coluna'];Tabela['coluna2'])`, assim ele faz a divisão respeitando os Ids. Depois altere a quantidade de casas decimais.

Comment: Bom dia, é que neste caso eu preciso dividir o valor de baixo pelo de cima, então não iria funcionar. Obrigado

Comment: entendi, vou da uma olhada aqui para ver como e q faz isso. Lembro q no excel tem como

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você precisa ter uma tabela dimensão de calendário (para usar a função itenerante)

1. **Último Valor Selecionado** = `SELECTEDVALUE(Plan1[VALOR CONVERTIDO])`
2. **Último Valor Selecionado - 1** =

```
CALCULATE(
    [Último Valor Selecionado];
    DATEADD(
        dCalendario[Data];-1;MONTH
    )
)
```

3. **Medida** = 
   `[Último Valor Selecionado]/[Último Valor Selecionado - 1]`

Espero que atenda.

Comment: Boa tarde, e obrigado pela resposta. Mas neste caso, eu precisaria dividir sempre pelo primeiro valor da "tabela, no caso do ID9 precisaria dividir sempre por 3,21. Sabe dizer se existe alguma forma de resgatar o primeiro valor? Obrigado. Att.,

Answer (score 0):

[image: Modelo]

**Primeiro Valor Selecionado =**

```
> CALCULATE(
>     [Último Valor Selecionado];
>     FIRSTDATE(
>         ALLSELECTED(
>             Planilha1[DATA]
>         )
>     ) 
)
```

**Medida Desejada =**

```
[Último Valor Selecionado]/[Primeiro Valor Selecionado]
```